# Android traslucent statusbar and layout padding top

Tags: android, android-actionbar, padding

In my app i'm using actionbar with tabs and i want to color the status bar, so i'm using

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

to set status bar traslucent. After this the content of the layouts appears behind the actionbar.
[image]

In page layout, i'm using

```
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

as suggested by google here
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Maybe the suggest is valid for actionbat only, without tabs, but how i can fix it if i'm using actionbar tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution here: [Translucent Theme in Android](https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/01/10/translucent-theme-in-android/).

I ended up abandoning that effect because `windowBackground` fills the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the status bar height like this: (src: https://github.com/kibotu/net.kibotu.android.deviceinfo/blob/cdc7009ac44159636bc6a49be07d92f035d19801/lib/src/main/java/net/kibotu/android/deviceinfo/library/display/Display.java#L78-L85)

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```